# I've got authentication error with Alpaca broker api

Tags: python, reactjs, django

Want some help from you.
I am working in Django/React project with Alpaca Broker APi    https://alpaca.markets/broker
https://prnt.sc/1sfzv9k

I am trying to get relationship ID. Btw I am getting the error like screenshot
Please help me if you have an expertise with Alpaca API

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, this error, basically means your API keys and Secret keys are incorrect. If that's the case, you need Regenerate new keys from Alpaca Broker Dashboard (please see screenshot) [image]

Alpaca Broker API must authenticate using HTTP Basic authentication. Use your correspondent API `key ID` and `secret` as the **username and password**. The format is `key_id:secret`. Encode the string with base-64 encoding, and you can pass it as an authentication header.

Since you're testing with Postman, you can select the Basic Auth and enter the credentials accordingly as stated above.
[image]

You may also check [here](https://alpaca.markets/docs/broker/api-overview/#authentication-and-rate-limit) in the Alpaca Broker API docs